# How to Select one Value for each row after Joining of 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, the first one has 10 distinct values:

[image: First Table],

each GlobalPnID has many values on the second table, I want to join 2 tables and select one random value of PortionKey of the second table that match the condition and move to the next GlobalPnID

[image]

```
SELECT  TOP 10 gpnp.PortionKey, tt.GlobalPnID 
from #TempTable tt
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[GlobalPartNumberPortions] gpnp  ON gpnp.GlobalPnId = tt.GlobalPnID

-- tt is the  first table
-- gpnp is the second
```

Comment: please avoid posting image. user text instead

Comment: Why does it need to be *random*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TT.GlobalPnID,X.PortionKey
FROM #TempTable AS TT
CROSS APPLY
 (
     SELECT TOP 1 R.PortionKey
       FROM [dbo].[GlobalPartNumberPortions] AS R
        WHERE R.GlobalPnId=TT.GlobalPnID
         ORDER BY R.PortionID
 )X
```

Comment: Or `ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` for a random row.

Comment: This won't do what you have requested.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Row_Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with a CTE and set the criteria you want, for example:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
  (
     globalpnid INT
  )
DECLARE @GlobalPartNumberPortions TABLE
  (
     portionid  INT,
     portionkey NVARCHAR(10),
     globalpnid INT
  )

INSERT INTO @TempTable
            (globalpnid)
VALUES      (1),(2),(3),(4)

INSERT INTO @GlobalPartNumberPortions
            (portionid,
             portionkey,
             globalpnid)
VALUES      (1,'ABC',1),
            (2,'XYZ',1),
            (3,'AZZ',2),
            (4,'QWE',3),
            (5,'TYU',4);

WITH cteportion
     AS (SELECT portionkey,
                globalpnid,
                rn = Row_number()
                       OVER (
                         partition BY globalpnid
                         ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))))
         FROM   @GlobalPartNumberPortions)
SELECT gpnp.portionkey,
       tt.globalpnid
FROM   @TempTable tt
       LEFT JOIN cteportion gpnp
              ON tt.globalpnid = gpnp.globalpnid
                 AND gpnp.rn = 1
```

This will partition the second table by the `globalpnid` ordering on `ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())))` and you can then use this in the join `gpnp.rn = 1`. In the example I've included, you'll see that GlobalPnID = 1 will alternate between **ABC** and **XYZ**.

**Edit**: as suggested by @Thorsten Kettner in the comment, you can order by `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())))`